# FancyApp & IE11 not working nested popups

Tags: jquery, fancybox, nested, internet-explorer-11

I have a new website that is being built for a client. On the product search page each item links to a detail page that opens as an iframe.

```
  $(".fbProduct").fancybox({
     type: 'iframe',
     padding: 0
  });
```

Those detail pages can have multiple thumbnail images.

When I try to open an image (nested in the first iframe) I can not close fancyApp or move to another page. The the left / right arrows are not visible, the close graphic is visible.

This worked fine in Firefox, Chrome, IE8,9 & 10.

Any ideas what is wrong? I can give you the URL if you think it would help.

```
http://75.103.118.60/Used/FORKLIFT/
```

Thanks,
Jordan